# ASP.NET MVC Custom Validation with Threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, validation

So I am looking to create custom validation of some form fields and need an idea how to approach this. Validation will connect to external api providers and check if data is unique.

This takes some time, so I was thinking to create validation in multiple threads with help of async controller(async, await).

So when I click submit button it connects to 3 different external apis and checks the data asynchronously.

What would be the best practice here? Or should I just create customValidation with inheriting ValidationAttribute ?

Thanks.

Comment: so is this external api calls from the javascript or from the controller?

Comment: server side through controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RemoteAttribute`. This attribute validates the input by calling an action in your MVC controller.

For example, we validate that name is unique

```
public class SampleModel
{
    [Remote("ValidateName" /*action*/, "Home" /*controller*/)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The ValidateName action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> ValidateName(string name)
    {
        //the external validator
        var externalValidators = new Func<string, Task<bool>>[] 
        {
            ExternalValidator1,
            ExternalValidator2,
            ExternalValidator3
        };

        //execute each asynchronously and wait for all to finish
        var externalValidatorTasks = externalValidators.Select(i => i(name)).ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(externalValidatorTasks);

        //return "invalid!" if any validation failed
        if (externalValidatorTasks.Any(i => !i.Result))
        {
            return Json("invalid!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //name is valid
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //mock external validation
    public Task<bool> ExternalValidator1(string name)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, this idea for multiple tasks helped me with solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom data validation DataAnnotation for this. 
In server side part of the validation attribute you can invoke the external APIs and in the client side part (validation adapter written in js/jQuery) make asynchornous calls to the external APIs.

You can check this for your reference: http://programersnotebook.blogspot.in/2013/03/customizing-validation-attributes-in-mvc.html